# how to open one div and in that div open another while hiding the first div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that when I click on dest button it shows me its content.

When I click, for example, on "north america" button, it opens just `north1` div content and hides `dest` content, and when I close `north1` div content that it's back to dest content.

```js
function dest() {
  var state = document.getElementById('dest').style.display;
  if (state == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('dest').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dest').style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function north() {
  var state = document.getElementById('north1').style.display;
  if (state == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('north1').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('north1').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.dest1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#d4418e, #0652c5);
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#dest {
  display: none;
}

.north0 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#d4418e, #0652c5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0px;
}

.north1 {
  display: none;
}

.south {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#d4418e, #0652c5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0px;
}

#sout {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <button type="button" class="dest1" id="dest1" onclick="dest()">Destination</button>



  <div class="dest" id="dest">
    <button class="north0" id="north0" onclick="north()">North America</button>



    <div class="north1" id="north1">
      <button class="green" id="green" onclick="green">Greenland</button>



      <button class="can" id="can" onclick="can">Canada</button>






      <button class="south" id="south" onclick="south()">South America</button>
      <div class="sout" id="sout">
        <button class="bra" id="bra" onclick="bra()">Brazil</button>
      </div>
      <button class="afri" id="afri" onclick="afri()">Africa</button>
      <button class="aus" id="aus" onclick="aus()">Australia</button>
      <button class="asi" id="asi" onclick="asi()">Asia</button>
      <button class="eur" id="eur" onclick="eur()">Europe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Display None

In the condition, where you update your second div *to show up* you can update your first div *to display none*

```
else {
    document.getElementById('dest1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('north1').style.display = 'block';
  }
```

```js
function dest() {
  var state = document.getElementById('dest').style.display;
  if (state == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('dest').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dest').style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function north() {
  var state = document.getElementById('north1').style.display;
  if (state == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('north1').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dest1').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('north1').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.dest1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#d4418e, #0652c5);
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#dest {
  display: none;
}

.north0 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#d4418e, #0652c5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0px;
}

.north1 {
  display: none;
}

.south {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#d4418e, #0652c5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0px;
}

#sout {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <button type="button" class="dest1" id="dest1" onclick="dest()">Destination</button>



  <div class="dest" id="dest">
    <button class="north0" id="north0" onclick="north()">North America</button>



    <div class="north1" id="north1">
      <button class="green" id="green" onclick="green">Greenland</button>



      <button class="can" id="can" onclick="can">Canada</button>

      <button class="south" id="south" onclick="south()">South America</button>
      <div class="sout" id="sout">
        <button class="bra" id="bra" onclick="bra()">Brazil</button>
      </div>
      <button class="afri" id="afri" onclick="afri()">Africa</button>
      <button class="aus" id="aus" onclick="aus()">Australia</button>
      <button class="asi" id="asi" onclick="asi()">Asia</button>
      <button class="eur" id="eur" onclick="eur()">Europe</button>
```